# C++ Differences between Linux and Windows with std::map

Tags: c++, linux, windows, stdmap

I'm trying to use a std::map to hold config details, however I'm getting different behaviour between Windows (Windows 8 64-bit) and Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit)

Below is the code snippet:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> testMap;

testMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("test1", "value1"));
testMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("test2", "value2"));

std::cout << testMap["test1"] << std::endl;
```

On windows this returns "value1" as expected, however on Linux this cause a Seg Fault.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What compiler and version is being used on Ubuntu?  Are the `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` options used?  If not, which ones?  Is the Ubuntu system building within an IDE?

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3 - neither of the -std=c++11 or -stdlib=libc++ options are used. This is built all on the command line in Ubuntu, not an IDE

Comment: No special options are being used?  I am not sure what g++ does regarding its default libraries.  Since using the `[]` operator is causing a seg fault, an incorrect (possibly old) STL library is being used with other libraries it is not compatible with.

Comment: This works fine for me on Ubuntu 13.10 amd64, and valgrind reports no errors.

Comment: I doubt the seg fault is caused by the operation on `std::map`, use `bt` (for backtrace) to get the stack trace.

Comment: Off topic: use make_pair instead of pair<string, string>() constructor

Comment: @oopscene I've tried it with both, and in fact I think the later versions of my code (after various trial and error) is using std::make_pair.

Comment: I tried doing a simple test (like the code above) on my work linux machine, and it doesn't have any issues. So there's definitely something (most likely memory corruption) happening previously. Will investigate further when I get a chance and post results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is fine and it works correctly on Linux machine.You have mentioned that you are getting the **segmentation fault**, while accessing the line, which indicates that your other logic of your program is doing some sort of memory corruption.

```
std::cout << testMap["test1"] << std::endl;
```

Heap corruption is often detected after the real corruption has already occurred by some DLL/module loaded within your process and current logic(where program is crashing) could be victim. However as this problem is observed on Linux machine, you many want to use **Valgrind**.This is the way you should attach your program(a.out).

```
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --db-attach=yes ./a.out
```

Valgrind would attach your program(**automatically**) in the debugger when your program detects  memory error so that you can do live debugging(GDB). This way you would get the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Hello - cheers for this. I had started to suspect some sort of memory corruption elsewhere after posting, but didn't have time to test it. I'll try and use GDB and Valgrind this evening to find more information. Sadly my debugging skills on Linux are lacking

Comment: @AndyEsser: Well you can share your testing result/log from Valgrind/GDB with SO community and we would try to help you out. But this is the way you can easily find such memory error :)..